# Adding syntax highlighting to Sublime Text for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2

i have a single problem, in my sublime text 2 the syntax highlight of javascript takes this code

```
this.init = function(){};
this.init : function(){},
```

painting of "this" in lightblue and "init" in green...

but in this case...

```
this.init = null;
this.init : null,
```

is not happening... i want to highlight "this.*" in all cases of use...

like for example

```
this.init = function()
this.init : function()
this.init : true
this.init = true
```

how can i do that???

Answer (score 6):

The default syntax highlighting for javascript in Sublime is not great.

I use JavascriptNext: https://github.com/Benvie/JavaScriptNext.tmLanguage

It improves on the default syntax hightlighting and also adds support for future ES6 syntax.

In your particular case it is more consistent on the coloring of the if values, though less consistent on the property values for the : syntax.  But I think thats ok since its not actually valid syntax anyhow.

[image: Comparison]

Comment: installing JavascriptNext by Package Control "this" are not in color... im using sublime text 2... –

Comment: Well it also depends on your syntax coloring.  That variable will be consistently colored with jsnext, but it may be the same color as other things  Try some different syntax highlighting, or if you want, design your own.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Been anoyed by the weird difference in the behaviour for quite a while now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [ben336's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18523437/1426065), I tested your code with my [Neon Color Scheme](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-sublime-theme) and a few different JavaScript language definitions, including [JavaScriptNext](https://github.com/Benvie/JavaScriptNext.tmLanguage), which actually did look the best:

[image: this.init with Neon theme]

The scopes for the `init` method are interesting (all are `source.js`, of course) -

```js
this.init = function(); // meta.property.js variable.other.property.js
this.init : function(); // meta.function.js meta.function.json.js entity.name.function.js
this.init : true; // meta.function.js constant.other.object.key.js string.unquoted.label.js
this.init = true; // meta.function.js meta.property.js variable.other.property.js
```

Since the last 3 are `function` scoped they should be colored bright green, but the third one has a `string` scope and the last one a `variable.other` scope, so they pick up those colorings instead.

If you'd like, I can try to finagle the theme's `function` scope selectors to color the last 3 consistently - just open [an issue](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-sublime-theme/issues/new) or let me know here and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: installing JavascriptNext by Package Control "this" are not in color... im using sublime text 2...

Comment: are you using the Neon Color Scheme, and have you chosen `JavaScriptNext` from the syntax menu?